# identify the click element and stop propagation when the element is <a>

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

The html section lick

```
<div id="aaa">
 ...<a id="a1">...</a>...<a id="a2">...</a>...
</div>
```

I want to add a click event to handle the click of div.
But all elements a have their click event handler. And the click event handler didn't stoppropagation, so it also will execute the div click event. And I cannot edit the element a's event handler and add stoppropagation().

How can I identify the click source element in the div's event handler? If it's an element a, I just return and do nothing.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the click event target tagname is an anchor return if it is.

```
document.getElementById('aaa').addEventListener("click", function(e){
  if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === "a") return;
});
```